# pcsc_scan doesn't work

Tags: pcscd

When I run pcsc_scan command, I got respond like it can't find my reader.

```
╰─➤  pcsc_scan

PC/SC device scanner

V 1.4.25 (c) 2001-2011, Ludovic Rousseau <ludovic.rousseau@free.fr>

Compiled with PC/SC lite version: 1.8.14

Using reader plug'n play mechanism

Scanning present readers...

Waiting for the first reader...
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, reader ACR122U.
It used to work on Linux Mint but i got reinstall to Ubuntu Xenial and here is the problem.
I have tried to install every possible dependencies packages but nothing helped. I hope there is a possibility to make it work on newer version Ubuntu.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

1. Disable kernel modules:

   ```
   modprobe -r pn533 nfc
   ```
2. Restart the pcscd daemon:

   ```
   sudo service pcscd restart
   ```